# Nodejs - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, api, express

I'm creating an API, in this particular route I'm getting this error.
First I upload my request.files in my firebase storage and then proceed to send the rest of the request data to my firestore. All of the data is properly storage without errors, but in my response, I only receive status code 404 and the following error on my console:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Here is my route:
`routes.post('/reports', Multer.array("images"), uploadImage, ReportsController.create);`

My upload:

```
export function uploadImage(request: Request, response: Response, next){
    if (!request.files) return next();
    const requestImages = request.files as Express.Multer.File[];
    const images = requestImages.map(image => {
        const fileName = Date.now() + "." + image.originalname.split(".").pop();
        const file = bucket.file("/images/" + fileName);
        const stream = file.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType: image.mimetype,
            },
        });
        // @ts-ignore
        stream.on("error", (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        stream.on("finish", async () => {
            await file.makePublic();
            next();
        });
        // @ts-ignore
        image.firebaseUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${BUCKET}//images/${fileName}`;
        stream.end(image.buffer);
    });
};
```

And my create function:

```
async create(request: Request, response: Response) {
        const requestImages = request.files as Express.Multer.File[];
        const images = requestImages.map(image => {
            return {path: image.firebaseUrl}
        });
        const {
            floodId,
            latitude,
            longitude,
            source,
            description,
            reportDate,
            status,
            range,
            hazards
        } = request.body;
        const hazardsJson = JSON.parse(hazards);
        const requestHazards = hazardsJson.map(hazard=> {
            return {type: hazard.type, status: hazard.status}
        });

        const report = new Report('', floodId, latitude, longitude, source, description, reportDate, status, range,
            images, requestHazards);
        const doc = await db.collection("reports").add({
            floodId: report.floodId,
            latitude: report.latitude,
            longitude: report.longitude,
            description: report.description,
            source: report.source,
            reportDate: report.reportDate,
            status: report.status,
            range: report.range,
            images: report.images,
            hazards: report.hazards,
        });
        return response.status(201).send(report);
    }
```

Comment: Does this problem happen when you send more than one file only? I'd suspect the `next()` call in `stream.finish` as all of that happens inside of the `map` over the array of files

Comment: Thanks @Narigo ! I removed the `next()` from `map` and worked!